# JPQL native query assistance required for Java Spring and postgress databse

Tags: database, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In my databse, there is two string column range1 and range2, I want to seach a int value which is between in this range1 and range 2.

I write this below psql query which is running fine.

```
SELECT * FROM data where code = 'DXB' and 5733 between range1::integer and range2::integer;
```

this query I wanted to replicate in my JPA repository interface, I tried this:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT r from data r where r.code=:code and " +
            ":serial  between CAST(r.range as int) and  CAST(r.range2 as int)",
            nativeQuery = true)
Data findBydatas(String code, int serial);
```

however, I am receving below error.
*org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; SQL [ SELECT r from data r where r.code=? and ?  between CAST(r.range as int) and  CAST(r.range2 as int)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query*

Comment: Please share the complete stacktrace not only the last line

Comment: As you use a native query, why you do not use the psql query you have?

Comment: I am new in PSQL, therefore I did not know how to write such kind of query. However, I found out that in these two columns, an empty value was present. I manually input data there and change it to int type. Now it is working fine. 
Btw thanks.